# Installation of MS Host Integration Server 2006

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server

We are in the process of upgrading from Windows 2003 R2 servers to Windows 2008 Standard Edition Service Pack 2 32 bit. We need to install Host Integration Server on this server, and it mentions connecting to SQL Server database from the configuration wizard. Is SQL Server a requirement to configure HIS 2006? If it is required could it be housed on a separate SQL server machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the installation documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770536(v=bts.10).aspx

> Configuration After Server Setup
>
> You can install the Server software
> without running the Configuration Tool, and then run the Configuration
> Tool later (on the Start menu). Eventually, however, you must run the
> Configuration Tool. To do this, you will need the software listed in
> the following table. It can either be installed on the local Host
> Integration Server or a remote computer.

So, SQL can be local or remote. You've got a bigger problem though. Per this document, HIS 2006 only supports SQL Server 2000 with Service Pack 3a. That is *old*. You may be able to dig further and see if newer versions are supported.

Also - you should definitely learn how to start doing your own research. That document was literally the first hit on Google for `host integration server 2006 installation guide`, which Google will helpfully autocomplete for you.

Comment: Thanks! I had visited that link, but did not see the SQL Server block. Also, MS is notorious for not updating their older documentation, which is also why I asked. For example, you said I had a bigger problem because the document only mentions SQL 2000 SP3A; however, we are running in production against SQL Server 2005, which MS never mentions. Google is great, but can't beat good old fashion experience. Either way I appreciate your help.

Comment: FYI - Just because it appears to work doesn't mean you won't run into a problem down the road.

Comment: Well we haven't run into a problem in 7 years, so I'm pretty sure we won't hit any issues. It's just MS wanting you to upgrade to their next release.